# Modify the class property inside the class function

Tags: php, class, this

I got the code from php.net website:

```
<?php
class foo {
    public $foo;
    public $bar;
    public function foo() {
        $this->foo = 'Foo';
        $this->bar = array('Bar1', 'Bar2', 'Bar3');
    }
}

$foo = new foo();
echo <<<EOT
I am printing some $foo->foo.
Now, I am printing some {$foo->bar[1]}.
EOT;
?>
```

But I'm confused, what is every "foo" stand for? Can you really modify the properties(variables) inside a method(function) without calling the function?

I write a similar code but nothing happened

```
<?php
class page {
    public $meta;
    public $buttons;
    public function show_meta() {
        $this->meta = "I'm a website";
        $this->buttons = array(
            "home" => "index.php",
            "about" => "about.php"
            );
    }
}

$index = new page();
echo $index->meta;
echo $index->buttons["home"];
?>
```

I'm a php learner, I need your help please :)

Comment: What error do you get for your code? You can modify variables because they are public, it they were private you wouldn't be able to do so.

Comment: I think if you declare the buttons array in the constructor, you'll get your desired result. The `show_meta()` method is not called hence your array is not initialized. You'll have to call the method atleast once, to initialize the array. Correct me if I'm worng

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`function foo` is a PHP4-style constructor (note that the function has the same name as the class). In PHP5 you would write `function __construct()` instead.

`new foo()` actually calls the constructor, initilizing your variables.

Answer (score 0):

On the first, yes, because your properties are `public`.

On the second case, you have reference with a string to remove the warning.

```
  $index->buttons["home"];
```

You never call `show_meta` so the array is never populated.

Answer (score 0):

this is the old php syntax for constructor methods. Constructors are Special methods, which are called, whenever a new object from the class is created. The new naming convention for constructors say, all constructors are named `__construct`.

To get the code above to work, you have to call show_meta, before accessing the two vars or make show_meta the constructor.

```
$index = new page();
$index->show_meta();
echo $index->meta;
echo $index->buttons["home"];
```

btw.. home is a string and should be inside "", or you raise at least a warning.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I am very appreciated it!